# C# Read file using GetModuleHandle API

Tags: c#, winapi

A while back I found a really nice snippet which showed how a file could be read using [GetModuleHanlde](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and a few other API. I now want to be able to read a file using this API but cannot get it to work. I know that `GetModuleHanlde` returns a handle to a file, and from there I believe that the [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx) API can be used to load the handle returned by `GetModuleHandle`. What I want to do is use this referenced handle to load the file into a byte array just like `File.ReadAllBytes` does.

Does anyone have a working example in either C#, VB.net, or VB6 (I am familiar with all three of these languages).

Comment: GetModuleHandle() is for getting an handle of a loaded module ( ie a DLL ) Loadlibrary is to load a dll in memory. Explain better what you want to do.

Comment: I want to load a file into a byte array without using File.ReadAllBytes (preferably by using GetmoduleHandle).

Comment: GetModuleHandle is not for "files", it give you an handle to a dll or an exe that is loaded in your process. Why do you hate ReadAllBytes ? If the file is to long just read it in chunks.

Comment: Do you mean something like GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32"), "**ReadFile**") ?

Comment: @Alex Yes, I belive this is what I am thinking of. I knew there was some way of doing it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `GetModuleHandle` returns a pointer into a memory-mapped dll is an *implementation detail*. This may change in any future Windows version, or even a Windows update.

If you need to read a file (including PE files), just use the regular file APIs.